# Add required attribute

Tags: jquery, html

There is a part of my HTML where I want to insert an attribute `required="required"`, but I can't find it. I would like to insert this part from jQuery and I tried with this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tags .bootstrap-tagsinput input.tt-input").attr("required", "required");
});
```

The HTML view from the browser is this:

```
<div class="competence tags">
    <label class="control-label required">Specializzazioni</label>
    <span class="tel-span">(inserire specializzazioni separate da una virgola)</span>
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
    <span class="twitter-typeahead" required="required">
    <input type="text" class="tt-hint" readonly=""required="required">
    **<input type="text" class="tt-input" autocomplete="off" >**
    </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like to put `required="required"` where the  `**` is.

How can this be done?

Comment: I might have overdone my edit, but this works just fine. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2vx1gfL/).

Comment: Did you include JQuery in your project? Also, you missing the closing `</div>` for your `div.competence.tags` element, and `</span>` for `span.twitter-typeahead`

Comment: Your jQuery looks correct, although you could use $('.tt-input").attr("required", "required"); unless you have other instances of that class in the page where you do not want this attribute.

Comment: fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/x12z1ava/

Comment: @Jurgemaister Not work.. i don't know..

Comment: @Vucko yes i cut a part of code but in my html there are..

Comment: @LucaM you should make your own fiddle as perhaps there is another issue preventing this function from firing? Are you seeing errors in the console? Is jquery available? Several comments and one answer here have links to fiddles showing this behaviour is working. So maybe you need to provide more information.

Comment: @LucaM This really has nothing to do with either JavaScript or Symfony2 even if you use it elsewhere in your project. Please remove the tags again.

Comment: @Iharby , for example if i put $(".tags").addClass("selected"); it works very well but if i write $(".bootstrap-tagsinput").addClass("selected"); not works... i don't know

Comment: Is the bootstrap class hard-coded into your page (it's not added later by some other javascript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're using a lot of selectors.

**Just to be clear, I'm thinking that your HTML looks like this:**

```
<div class="competence tags">
    <label class="control-label required">Specializzazioni</label>
    <span class="tel-span">(inserire specializzazioni separate da una virgola)</span>
    <div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
        <span class="twitter-typeahead" required="required"></span>
        <input type="text" class="tt-hint" readonly=""required="required">
        <input type="text" class="tt-input" autocomplete="off" >
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use the following selector:

```
$(".tt-input").attr('required','required');
```

**If you want only the children of 'tags' class:**

```
$('.tags').children('.bootstrap-tagsinput').each(function(idx, obj) {
    $(obj).children('.tt-input').attr('required','required')
});
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Maybe he only wants to target this specific input.

Comment: @Eleazar Enrique i tried ` $('.tags').children('.bootstrap-tagsinput').children('.twitter-typeahead').children('.tt-input').attr('required','required'); `   but nothing... i don t know why.. @Eleazar Enrique

Comment: @EleazarEnrique i edit my html code, not work with your last edit.. Sorry

Comment: Read my comment in the answer.  Is that the html in your code?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem infact if i put $(".tags").addClass("selected"); it works very well but if i write $(".bootstrap-tagsinput").addClass("selected"); not works... i don't know @EleazarEnrique

Comment: I think your problems are the dashes.  What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95044/discussion-between-luca-m-and-eleazar-enrique).